# What holomorphic functions $f$ satisfy $|f(z)| \leq |z|^k$ for all $z$ ∈ C?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I go about thinking about this? I can't think of anything that works for all z!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Since $|{f(z) \over z^k }| \le 1$ for all $z \neq 0$ we see that $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z=0$, hence $g(z) = {f(z) \over z^k }$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and so $g$ can be taken to be entire (and bounded).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! What do you mean by 'entire'?

Comment: @Taimur: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function

Comment: Analytic on all of $\mathbb{C}$.